# wordpress admin missing Posts button

Tags: posts

[[image: 2]

I have multiple wordpress account with identical plugins. On 2 of them, I note that 'Posts' word is missing. It is appearing on my other wordpress account. It should appear below 'Avada'. I am using wordpress 5.6.1 . My plugins are up to date. Might anybody know why it is missing?

Avada: Version 5.2.1

Comment: Deactivate your plugins one by one, does it appear again?

Comment: Possibly those 2 sites have different capabilities set for Post?

Comment: I have discovered that if I type <websitename>wp-admin/edit.php , I am still able to see the Posts